# Edit OEM DMI Strings in UEFI ROM

Tags: bios, uefi, rom

I need to modify the OEM DMI Strings of a UEFI ROM.

I used the Phoenix BIOS Editor for doing the same thing on legacy BIOS ROMs, but now I need to modify a UEFI ROM which does not work on the Phoenix BIOS Editor.

I know there is a Phoenix UEFI Editor, but aswell as the BIOS Editor, it's abandonware that is nowhere to be found.

Does anybody knows an alternative method or have a download link for the UEFI Editor?